# Saving the pyspark dataframe to multiple AWS S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am currently working on the use case, where

1. I want to write each partition to different S3 bucket.
2. Want to know, If I write the whole dataframe into single S3 bucket whose size is around 50GB then how the saved data would look like into bucket assuming I'm writing the data in `JSON` format; to be more specific, what would be file name in S3 when the dataframe is saved.

Comment: Can you please take some time and reformulate the question? It is really hard to understand what your question is.

Comment: @RobertKossendey : I have updated the question details as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you want to write each partition in a separate bucket?

To your second question: The saved data would depend on the amount of partitions you are saving to S3. You can always repartition the data by calling `.repartition()` on your data frame. Since the files are saved in the Hadoop File Format, the name will contain some specific numbers and a -part suffix similar to this: `part-block-0-0-r-00000-.json`

Comment: This is what I wanted to know exactly what would be name the of the partitions when they will be saved into S3. Thanks !!